# Getting router errors trying to deploy to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have an app that works locally and is basically Posting to mailchimp.  When I try to deploy to Heroku I am getting these errors.

```
2019-01-04T22:16:17.633067+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user briankaty1@me.com
2019-01-04T22:16:20.218913+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2019-01-04T22:16:22.833691+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-01-04T22:16:22.853329+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-01-04T22:16:26.779902+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2019-01-04T22:16:29.728985+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-01-04T22:16:29.623338+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
2019-01-04T22:16:29.623365+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-01-04T22:16:29.623367+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-01-04T22:16:29.623369+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-04T22:16:29.623370+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2019-01-04T22:16:29.623373+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
```

Can anyone help me and tell me what this means?  It doesn't make sense that if this works locally should it not work with Heroku?
Here are the lines proceeding these ones.  I have installed express and done `nom install` is there anything I am missing?

Comment: We would need the lines that precede that line in the heroku logs.

Comment: I checked the logs and it crashed when you deployed it, not when you visited the site, is that right?

Comment: when I tried to visit the site.  Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: So could it be in the code?

Comment: Check if all required depencies are listed in package.json and check the environment variables, end if you have a Procfile can you please upload that to here?

Comment: These are the only dependancies I have in package.json file ```"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }``` There should be more.  Why is it missing these ```const express = require ('express');
const bodyparser = require ('body-parser');
const request = require ('request');```